# Returning dom element from json

Tags: javascript, json, dom, reactjs, webpack

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "HOME_VIEW_CONTENT": {
    "header": "<div>Hello <span className='someClass'>world!</span></div>",
    "ingress": "Hello moon!"
  }
}
```

then in react I have this code:

```
{content.header}
{content.ingress}
```

And this works, but i'm getting the div out as a string (naturally).
Is there a plugin or an easy way to convert the string with the div to an div object without using dangerouslyInsertInnerHtml in react?

I am using a webpack + react setup so i might use a loader? or Is there a react method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

React escapes the HTML to prevent XSS. 
If you really want to render HTML, you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML:

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.actions}}
```

React has this syntax so that you don't accidentally render text as HTML and introduce XSS bugs.

This is from the docs, i have not tested this as i did not need it so far.

Comment: ended up with this `<div className="View Home">
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content.header}}></div>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content.ingress}}></p>
      </div>` but it would be nice to not have to dangerously insert code into an dom element.

Comment: The method is set to that name especially to warn users of the fact that it is dangerous. Seems to me you should have templates for that and just inject contents... Not a react power user

Comment: I use it for a json that holds all text on the webpage, and I would like to use this kind of implementation so I can set something bold or make something a link without hardcoding that into my compiled code. This json data will never be updated by any one other than me so no harmful code will be made. I see react jsx as teplating enough, and it should be a handy way to do this, but this is as good as I got it for now.

Comment: The mere method name used is a hint that you are using it wrong, but they allow you to do so.